# Using WCF service as a outbound endpoint from a mule flow

Tags: esb, mule

I have a wcf service that i have created that i'd like my mule server to push messages (custom objects) to at the end of a certain flow.

Now, i cant seem to find any working examples of such an implementation ( i realize they both support soap).

Is there soem sort of online example i can use? Is there anyway where i dont need to create 2 implementation of my custom object (both a java and a c# one)?

I've seen the cxf endpoint but it requires a WSDL file (which i can get from the wcf service endpoint) as well as a class implementing a service which i dont know how to make.

How would i go about creating this? I'd love an example for such a thing if it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow procedure 1 (WSDL First JAX-WS Client) of the [Consuming Web Services](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Consuming+Web+Services+with+CXF) with CXF section of Mule User Guide.